# Google AppEngine: do Google employees have any access to my Python source codes?

Tags: google-app-engine

My concern is that anyone in Google can have some access to my uploaded (and published) source codes in plain text. And, what about data stored in DataStore? Are they protected?

I'm using Python 2.7 runtime and, of course, I can make it 'undownloadable' if that helps in some ways.

Comment: maybe the mailing list is more appropriate place for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible that some employee might be able to look at your code and/or data by trying really hard, breaking their employment contract with Google and possibly becoming a law-breaker. I think that's highly unlikely, though.

If you're concern is more around the intellectual property with regards to your code+data, Google's stance regarding that is [explicit](http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html):

> Customer owns all Intellectual Property Rights in any Application and Customer Content, and Google owns all Intellectual Property Rights in the Service.

So at no point of time are they going to look at your code+data and copy anything. Doing so will open the door to your taking them to court immediately.

I think Google takes measures to solve this problem on a much larger scale then what relates to your and my applications on GAE. Compared to the data that it needs to protect from all human eyes, we're fairly unimportant :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why this is particularly a problem with AppEngine. Any hosting provider is always going to have access to your code, simply because they own the disks that it lives on. You simply have to believe their code of conduct, if they have one, or that they really don't care about your code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the *Confidential Information* section of the [Google App Engine Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html).

In practice, both your code and your data are probably *lost in the noise* as far as Google are concerned.